# Migrate database between 2 different wordpress version

Tags: database, updates

I have been trying to import a sql dump from a production site, which is several wp version behind the development site (4.1), is there any compatibility issue? Every time I try to login after the db is updated, I get the "Database needs to update" warning, after that I get logged in but the home page is partially broken.
I would appreciate any ideas or advices about this. Thanks

Comment: You should describe, how exactly the home page is broken. Some notifications? Warnings? Errors?

Comment: There were not errors, just after menu everything below is blank.

Comment: Is debugging enabled in wp-config.php file? Maybe then we could see some errors. define('WP_DEBUG', true);